# How do I divide URL parameters in a URL route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

How would I set up the URL routing for a scenario such as this:

www.website.com/[project name]/News/Submit/[possible extra parameters]

[project name] = a variable that will be needed by the action to specify which project
News = Controller
Submit = Action
[possible extra parameters] = id

I have yet to run into any examples of how to accomplish this yet.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute("myroute", "{projectname}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = "" });
```

Then your action methods will have a projectname and an id parameter.

If your question is how to route using multiple actual web applications, then you're in a whole other world :)